# ¿Como ocultar un elemento que tiene la misma clase que otro elemento con Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, magento2

estoy tratando de hacer un hover con Jquery pero no tengo exito, al pasar el mouse se me activa el hover para ambos elementos pero quiero que solo afecte al que le paso el mouse, aun asi quiero que mantengan la misma clase ya que se generan automaticamente. dejo imagenes de el antes y el despues del hover. NOTA: si se puede hacer por LESS mejor.

Antes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Despues:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo en Jquery hasta el momento:

```
requirejs(['jquery', 'domReady!'], function ($) {
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.result-thumbnail').hover(function(){
        $('.result-sub-content').css("display", "block");
        $('.result-sub-content').css("transition", "all 1.5 ease");
        }, function(){
        $('.result-sub-content').css("display", "none");
    });
    $('.result-sub-content').hover(function(){
        $('.result-sub-content').css("display", "block");
        $('.result-sub-content').css("transition", "all 1.5 ease");
        });
})
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para empezar te diría que es mucho más más fácil si lo hicieras con CSS

```
.result-sub-content:hover .result-sub-content{
    display:block;
     ...
}
```

Comment: Me a servido tu respuesta, solo que le agregue un ~ de este modo: .result-sub-content:hover ~ .result-sub-content{ display:block; ... } muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

No entiendo la segunda parte. Si al hacer `hover` sobre `.result-thumbnail` mostrás `.result-sub-content`, que sentido tiene volver a mostrarlo cuando hacés `hover` sobre sí mismo?

Dentro del `hover` tenés que seleccionar la clase que está dentro del elemento. Para eso poder utilizar [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/).

```
$('.result-thumbnail').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.result-sub-content').css("display", "block");
    $(this).find('.result-sub-content').css("transition", "all 1.5 ease");
}, function () {
    $(this).find('.result-sub-content').css("display", "none");
});

$('.result-sub-content').hover(function () {
    $(this).css("display", "block");
    $(this).css("transition", "all 1.5 ease");
});
```

Ahora, sería conveniente que todo esto lo hagas directamente desde CSS:

```
.result-sub-content {
  display: none;
  transition: all 1.5 ease;
}

.result-thumbnail:hover .result-sub-content {
  display: block;
}
```

El `transition` no se a que se lo estarás aplicando, porque a la propiedad `display` no le podes aplicar una transición.

---

Estoy adivinando la estructura HTML, deberías publicarla.